# SQL Combining two joins

Tags: sql, join

I would say my understanding of SQL is average, but I am wondering if there is any way to more efficiently write this statement?

The primary key of table `Company` is `uniqentity` and has the company name `nameof` in that row.

In the table `Line`, the primary key is `uniqline` and I have columns `entityCompanyBilling` and `entityCompanyIssuing` (both foreign keys to `uniqentity`).

This code below works just fine, I am just trying to make it more efficient. Is it possible?

```
SELECT 
   l.uniqline, b.nameof AS billingcompany, 
   l.UniqEntityCompanyBilling, i.nameof AS issuingcompany, 
   l.UniqEntityCompanyIssuing
FROM 
   Line l 
INNER JOIN 
   Company b ON b.uniqentity = l.uniqentitycompanybilling
INNER JOIN 
   Company i ON i.uniqentity = l.uniqentitycompanyissuing
```

Comment: If it works fine, why change it?  Is it running slow or something?

Comment: I am being challenged to clean up some SQL codes, make it run more efficiently.  This was bugging me as it looks repetitive, but then again I guess it really is not.

Comment: YOu  should ask if it is efficient not how to condense it.

Comment: Check ExplainPlan cost,if that is high then we can think of reducing it further..but check which join is costly and we can try using inner sql to reduce join cost..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the structure of the *query* may not make it more efficient (it seems to be as simple as it can be).  But changing the structure of the *data* might:

- Add indexes (if not already) on `UniqEntityCompanyBilling` and `UniqEntityCompanyIssuing`
- <strike>Add index on `Company.UniqEntity`</strike> <sup>Didn't catch that the column is the PK</sup>
- If the index on `Company.UniqEntity` isn't clustered, include the  `nameof` field in the index on `Company.UniqEntity` so the query doesn't have to go back to the physical table.

Answer (score 1):

This query is perfectly fine as it is.

You could make it shorter like below, but this will decrease readability and is generally considered bad practice, so don't.

```
SELECT l.uniqline, b.nameof AS billingcompany, l.UniqEntityCompanyBilling, i.nameof AS issuingcompany, l.UniqEntityCompanyIssuing
FROM Line l, Company b, Company i
WHERE b.uniqentity = l.uniqentitycompanybilling
AND i.uniqentity = l.uniqentitycompanyissuing
```

Comment: Using `WHERE` to join tables instead of using ANSI-standard joins is a giant anti-pattern.  Don't make their code worse.

Answer (score 1):

You can include filters to the joining to the tables, if possible, as below:

```
SELECT 
   l.uniqline, b.nameof AS billingcompany, 
   l.UniqEntityCompanyBilling, i.nameof AS issuingcompany, 
   l.UniqEntityCompanyIssuing
FROM 
   Line l 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT *
    FROM Company
    WHERE <REGION = 'xyz', etc.>
   ) b ON b.uniqentity = l.uniqentitycompanybilling
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT *
    FROM Company 
    WHERE <REGION = 'xyz', etc.>
   ) i ON i.uniqentity = l.uniqentitycompanyissuing
WHERE <any filter condition>;
```